# If a DFA is minimized, is it guaranteed that it's complement is also minimized?

Tags: finite-automata, computation-theory, deterministic

Consider there is a minimized DFA that accepts the language L. The problem is to find the minimum number of states in its complement.

Now if I take the complement of this DFA i;e if I make the non-final states as final and final states as non-final, do I also need to worry about minimizing this complemented DFA?

DFA - Deterministic Finite Automata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with that [image: L1] is accepted by a minimum DFA [image: D1]. Then we can retrieve the DFA of the complement (as you have mentioned). So let's derive a DFA [image: D2] which accepts [image: L1'] which has the same amount of states as [image: L1] .

Now Lets assume that [image: D2] is not a minimum DFA of [image: L1']

we should be able to reduce the number of states in it further to get a DFA [image: D3]. But getting the complement of [image: D3] should give us a new DFA [image: D4] which accepts [image: (L1')'] which is [image: L1] but has less states than [image: D1] making it not a minimum DFA of [image: L1].

So our assumption that [image: D2] not being the miniumum of [image: L1'] is wrong.